# How to increment an array of 8-bit values in JavaScript like a clock?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Say I am representing a very large number using only 8-bit values in an array. Say the array is 32 8-bit values long. It starts out as 0. I'll just draw 4 8-bit values to demonstrate.

```
[0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Then it counts up.

```
[0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 2]
...
[0, 0, 0, 255]
```

Once it gets to 255 in the first column, it goes to the next column.

```
[0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 2]
...
[0, 0, 1, 255]
[0, 0, 2, 0]
[0, 0, 2, 1]
...
[0, 0, 2, 255]
[0, 0, 3, 0]
[0, 0, 3, 1]
...
```

After filling that up, it goes to the 3rd column, then upon filling that out, it goes to the fourth column, etc..

```
[0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 2]
[0, 1, 0, 3]
...
[0, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 2]
...
[0, 1, 2, 0]
[0, 1, 2, 1]
...
...
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 2]
...
[1, 0, 0, 255]
[1, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 1]
...
...
...
[2, 0, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 0, 1]
...
...
...
and so on.
```

How do you write an algorithm to increment these values like this. As if it were a single humongous value, which is just represented using smaller 8-bit values. It is mind-bending for me and I haven't been able to accomplish it.

Actually, I'm not sure I have drawn it in reverse, I was thinking about numbers as reading from smallest position on the right to the larger position on the left, which is why I drew it this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a simple for loop (see snippet below, should be pretty self-explanatory)

```js
let number = [0,0,255,250];

const add = () => {
  for ( let i = number.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
    if(number[i]===255){
      number[i] = 0;
    } else {
      number[i]++;
      break;
    }
  }
  console.log(number);
}
```

```html
  <button onclick="add()">add</button>
```

Comment: Can you show how it would be if you did the numbers from left to right instead of right to left? And also, how can you tell if you are done counting? I.e. there is no more space in the array.

Comment: Just invert the for loop: `for (let i = 0; i < number.length - 1; i++)`

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you meant...

```js
function increase(ar){
    ar[0] = ar[0] + 1;
    for(let i = 0; i < ar.length-1; i++){
       ar[i+1]+= ar[i] < 256 ? 0 : 1;
       ar[i] = ar[i] < 256 ? ar[i] : 0;
    }
    return ar;
}
let res = [250,1,0,0];
for(let u = 0; u < 10; u++){
      console.log(increase(res));
}
```

It can be by far more generalized, changing the limit and also increasing by `N` (in this case it increase only by 1).

A possible implementation is the following:

```js
function increase(ar, step = 1, limit = 256){
    ar[0] = ar[0] + step;
    for(let i = 0; i < ar.length-1; i++){
       ar[i+1]+= ar[i] < limit ? 0 : Math.floor(ar[i] / limit);
       ar[i] = ar[i] < limit ? ar[i] : ar[i] % limit;
    }
    return ar;
}
let res = [248,0,0,0];
for(let u = 0; u < 10; u++){
    console.log(increase(res, 3));
}
```